# Running BLDC motor using Solar Panel

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, solar-energy

**I have a 1250W 48V BLDC motor**
Can anyone suggest me what combination of solar panels I should use to best run my BLDC motor .
 I wanted to run my electric vehicle solely on solar energy . 
Thank you!

Comment: What performance do you expect?

Comment: What do you mean by performance ?@GregoryKornblum

Comment: Have you calculated how many square meters of solar panels you need to get the amount of power you would like to propel your vehicle?

Comment: Performance - current, voltage, power, peak and continuous, all depend on application requirements and all affect your solar panels.

Comment: @john D 190cm (width) * 300cm(lengthy) at max

Comment: Do you live in Australia, or Finland?

Comment: @Neil_UK I am from India

Comment: @gregory kornblum 30 amps current , 48 v

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Just buy the highest output power panels you can fit in your vehicle envelope (1.9m x 3m). Don't expect to go very fast, and forget about climbing hills.

Comment: @mkeith actually I am a beginner in these kind of things . So I was asking if you can suggest anything .

Comment: My suggestion is that you look for all the panels you can find and make a list, preferably in a spreadsheet. Include size, power, cost for each panel. Your goal should be to maximize power, but still fit on your vehicle. It will not be possible to have enough power for good performance. So you just need to focus on fitting maximum power in the space available.

Comment: 30 amps continuously? Why 48V? Did actually check with your mechanics?

Comment: ... so fairly sunny then. Buy a panel, set it up, monitor its output, compare power availability with your estimated needs. I agree with mkeith that you can't have too much power on a practical size vehicle, so go for the max. Will you have rechargable battery backup? Do you ever want to drive at night? If you have a battery, you could climb hills reasonably well.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum 30 amps max . Actually i tested my vehicle with 48V 100ah lead acid battery . So i saw 30 amps current in the reading . it was max reading .

Comment: @Neil_UK i have li-ion battery 48V 50ah to run it . But i was more concentrating on running it solely on solar power on a flat surface.

Comment: Again, was it continuous? Or just for one second to start moving? In fact I don't really care, just want you to know that it is not as simple as one number and you get your solar panel.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum No sir it wasnt constant . It varied with my acceleration pedal . But at the start it was 30 amp .

Comment: Ok, so just to illustrate the situation, power you consumed was 30A times very low voltage (because speed was low), maybe 150W. So to define your solar panel you must create this performance envelope, showung maximum values at each situation. Then you will need to see, if some of requirements are applicable to solar panels, or maybe your motor drive can take care of them. And so on... Bloody system design!

Comment: @GregoryKornblum thanks for the advice . But the problem is that my partners in my project wanted me to tell them the exact dimension of my solar panels as they wanted to design the car on solid works .

Comment: The exact dimensions of the solar panel are the biggest the car allows, or the biggest the team's budget allows, because even with that size, the performance will be disappointing.

Comment: It's indeed a problem. Because how can you design something if your requirements are not clear? One way is do make a guess (or call it estimation), build a model and see what's wrong about it. If you have time and money for that- very good. In my career that way never worked out well. On the other hand, if you can carefully define all requirements, you will be able to design whatever you want. By the way, are even sure the panel you need exists? It may very well appear during the design, that there is no solution for your problem or market.

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks for the advice . are flexible solar panels better bcoz i am using tadpole configuration for my car .

Comment: @GregoryKornblum please see this . i wanted to participate in an event . http://www.ashmanmotors.com/design/rulebook/Indo-Asian-Solar-Challenge.pdf

Comment: To add to Neil's comment, the car could come out as a hybrid with PV to only be one source of energy. But again, for that expectations must be clear

Comment: What do you want me to see there? I will not participate...

Comment: @GregoryKornblum haha. no i dont want you to participate . i wanted to show you the design and the requirements.

Comment: Ha! Not to me. You are going to design your system, i have mines to work on :)

Comment: @GregoryKornblum ha! No problem sir . That's why I asked for suggestion s not for solutions

Comment: Ok, but you see now there is whole document for the requirements. Even without reading it it's clear that you didn't provide all information in your question. And even if you would, no one would design the system for you... Sorry, but it's too complicated for a forum. You see, even a statement "as big PV as you can" requires some number to actually know what will happen with each square meter of the pv.

Comment: Anyway Thanks for the help and time you gave . @GregoryKornblum

Comment: My brother asked me a year ago to join his team for the trans-Australia solar car race. Very wisely, I declined. He's now beginning to see the wisdom of that decision, as he takes in the full horror of the engineering commitment he's entered into. If you want some real advice, the most useful advice you will read on this question, if you value your sanity, do not get yourself into such an engineering challenge!

Comment: @Neil_UK sorry sir but I already applied for this event but thanks for the advice and don't feel offended but I thought you were from UK as in your name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a 1250W 48V BLDC motor Can anyone suggest me what combination of solar panels I should use to best run my BLDC motor . I wanted to run my electric vehicle solely on solar energy . Thank you!

The extensive comments have given you a guide to how complex this is likely to be.The following addresses your basic question.

The voltage is important but secondary.
Panel power is the greatest initial consideration.

You say you require 1250 Watts.
A typical monocrystalline silicon PV panel will provide a module power of about 150 Watts in full sun at midday when the panel is at 25C.
Market leading "rear contact" panels may produce about 200 W/m^2 in the same conditions.

Orienting the panel at an angle to the sun will reduce power by an amount able to be calculated by simple geometry. This may happen due to
 - the sun is off line (not mid-day)
 - the tadpole shape is not fully sun oriented at the point under consideration
 - the car is moving at a non optimum angle
 - ...

As the panel heats power output will drop - see datasheets

Shading part of the panel will affect the output drastically unless special attention is paid to bypassing shaded cells electrically.

Flexible panel material will generally be of lower output per area but spec sheets will tell you what to expect.

For a flat sun facing panel when heated by the sun an output of say 130 W/m^2 would be doing well.
So 1250 W would require 1250/130 =~ 10 square meters if sun facing panels.

A look through the challenge document shows an all up weight allowed of 300 kg. I did not see a size limit. 10 square metres of panel would require a say 5m x 2m slab. I suspect that that is somewhat larger than anyone expects.

This sort of panel [example only](https://www.altestore.com/store/solar-panels/canadian-solar-255-watt-smart-module-with-solaredge-optimizer-p40428/) weighs about 80 kg/1000_Watts so would be notionally able to be used within the weight limit.
In practice you have much less area available and much is not sun facing. If you calculate the maximum surface area that you can mount cells on and the effective sun facing area for all sun angles, then you will be able to get some idea of what can be achieved.  And then, the work starts ... :-(.

**__________________________**

An excellent site for scoping PV panels - [**Vast number of panels with specs and pricing**](https://www.altestore.com/store/solar-panels-c541/)  - click link to right of images for details.